# class_eval block argument and class_eval string argument differences

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To simplify my situation, I have a module which is loaded into Mongoid::Document when my Rails app is initialized:

```
Mongoid::Document.send(:include, ActiveRecordBridge)
```

This module defines a method:

```
def has_many_records(*records)
  options = records.extract_options!
  if options[:polymorphic]
    class_eval <<-EOS
      def #{ record }
        @#{ record } ||= #{ record.to_s.singularize.classify.constantize }.where( document_id: String(id), document_type: self.class.name)
      end
    EOS
  end
end
```

Now my Mongoid class makes use of it:

```
class Something
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many_records :something_else, polymorphic: true
end
```

This has worked great, but then another developer added the [sync](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync) gem into my system, and has made use of it in the SomethingElse class:

```
class SomethingElse < ActiveRecord::Base
  sync :all
end
```

As soon as I start up the Rails app, I am hit with the following exception:

```
Uncaught exception: undefined method `sync' for #<Class:0x007fb7910530c0>
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activerecord-4.1.5/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
    /Users/donato/projects/core revisions/core/app/models/something_else.rb:73:in `<class:Task>'
    /Users/donato/projects/core revisions/core/app/models/something_else.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:480:in `load_missing_constant'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:180:in `const_missing'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
    /Users/donato/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@core/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
    /Users/donato/projects/core revisions/core/lib/active_record_bridge.rb:55:in `block in has_many_records'
```

Here is the interesting part. When I replace the string argument to class_eval with a block, the error goes away:

```
      class_eval do
          def something_elses
            @something_elses ||= SomethingElse.where(document_id: String(id), document_type: self.class.name)
          end
        end
```

While this works, this is not what I want, because now I am explicitly writing something_else rather than using string interpolation.

**My question: What about the string argument that would cause this error, while the block argument does not?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're passing in the string argument you're interpolating `record.to_s.singularize.classify.constantize`. The last call to `constantize` tries to find the constant `SomethingElse`. Rails apps in development are usually set up to lazily load their classes, so only at this point does the app try to load the file containing `SomethingElse` and since the file contains an error it is encountered while loading.

In the second case a reference to `SomethingElse` is not reached until you actually call `something_elses` meaning that only at that point will the file be loaded and the error encountered. You can try starting up a console and calling that method or just typing in `SomethingElse` - both should raise the error.

Comment: class_eval with the block does not raise the error at all. That was the point of my question. The error is only raised when the string is passed.

Comment: Do you think that my initializer is being invoked before some other initialization required by sync? Because in my initializer I specify this file to be loaded first prefixing it with 01_ and then I also notice in my initializer there is another file sync_core whihc is being loaded after. If the second call isn't called until later, then it would make sense for it not to throw an error, since maybe that other initializer is required before the class is loaded.

Comment: But then again, aren't the classes loaded before any of the initializers?

Comment: I think classes are by default only loaded when they are used

Comment: I got this issue again, but this time it was devise causing the error. You are right in the sense that the string is evaluated and tries to load the constant. At that time, since that initializer is being run before the initializer that is used to configure the class, the error occurs. When I change the priority of the initiializers and make sure all the configuration of classes is initialized first, and then load my initializers that use them, then the error goes away. It was your answer that led me to the right path and thus I mark it correct.